# Usage of optimism

Tags: meaning, word-usage, context

Optimism usually suggests a positive, hopeful attitude. However, does it always have to be related to a silver lining in a cloud?

For example,

> James got fired from his job. Look on the bright side! That gives him more time to pursue his hobbies.

That’s optimism.

But another example,

> The weather today is lovely for a hike!

Is that optimism?

Answer (score 3):

Optimism is *hoping for/expecting* the best. Saying it's a nice day for a hike isn't optimism, but saying "It's cloudy now, but I'm sure the sun is going to come out later" is.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries list a related sense of *optimism*, seeing the best in an existing situation, the antithesis of cynicism. *But there is always an expectation of good, a sense of hope ... however naive.*

> **optimism** [noun] [non-count]
>
> *the tendency to be hopeful and to emphasize or think of the good part in a situation rather than the bad part*, or the feeling that in the
> future good things are more likely to happen than bad things

[[Cambridge Dictionary; emphasis mine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/optimism)]

> **optimism** [noun]
> *a disposition or tendency to look on the more favorable side of events or conditions* and to expect the most favorable outcome.

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/optimism)] (which also lists other senses relating to belief systems)